# React opening a new page on link click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I open/direct to a page on link click using **ReactJS**.

From `index.html` I want to provide a link to open a new page. I have added the following  code

```
import React from 'react';
class Header extends React.Component {  
render() {
    return 
             <div> 
                <a href="#/TrialUser"> Trial User</a>
            </div>  
}
export default Header;
```

It doesn't open that page. Do I need to update the `app.js` or `router.js` file to add the link.

Comment: What do you mean by "view"?

Comment: you may want to reconsider your need to use yet another js framewrok if making a link to another page requires you to ask about it on so.

Comment: You're not linking to another page, you're linking to a fragment (using the hash mark). So your real question is about routing, not linking to a page. And you should probably show what's in router.js to get a good answer.